# How does renormalization affect divergent subdiagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities

Suppose we have a theory that is super-renormalizable and let $\Gamma^n$ denote the sum of all 1PI diagrams of this theory with $n$ amputated external legs. In such theories, for all $n$ sufficiently large, $\Gamma^n$ is superficially convergent. For those $n$ for which $\Gamma^n$ superficially diverges, the divergences occur to only order in perturbation theory and so we only need a finite number of renormalizations, i.e. only a finite number of Feynman diagrams are divergent.

I have read in numerous places that even though $\Gamma^n$ may be superficially convergent, it may contain divergent subdiagrams. However, for super-renormalizable theories I have also read that once the necessary (and in this case finite) number of renormalizations have been carried out, the divergent subdiagrams will now also be convergent.

This fact is not immediately obvious to me. How do the finite number of renormalizations for $\Gamma^n$ with $n$ sufficiently small handle the divergent subdiagrams of $\Gamma^n$ for lage $n$? Is there some intuitive reason as to why this should be true? Where can I find a proof of this fact?

Also, is it true that the same applies to renormalizable theories, but now they would require an infinite number of renormalizations since there are divergences at all orders in perturbation theory for all $\Gamma^n$ with $n$ sufficiently small?